# Laravel relationship between three tables with two foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to show information of checkout_pages table that has two foreign keys that needs to be validated.

- users

  - id
- products

  - id
  - user_id
- checkout_pages

  - id
  - user_id
  - product_id

The product has an owner (products.user_id), the checkout_pages has relationships between users and products. I need to show the information about checkout_pages for the specific user and specific product (not necessarily the product owner).

I make some code, but it only validate the checkout_pages.product_id and I can't make it validate the checkout_pages.user_id.

Model Product

```php
    public function checkout_pages(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\CheckoutPage');
    }
```

ProductController

```php
 public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all()->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id);
        return view('products.index', compact('products'));
    }
```

**Edit**

- User can have multiple checkout_pages, but of different products
- This is the code I have now, I know it isn't validating the checkout_pages table, but looking through the Laravel Doc I couldn't find an answer
- I need to get this infos from checkout_pages in the ProductController.

Comment: This code doesn't validate anything, it gets data from the database and sends it to a view. What is the question exactly? Maybe you meant something else than "validate"?

Comment: what do you mean by **foreign keys that needs to be validated.**?

Comment: @kheengz I need to get the checkout_pages register to show to a specific user(checkout_pages.user_id). So the user will see only his own checkout_pages of all products (checkout_pages.product_id) he applied for. The validation of products table is ok (only the owner/user can see his own product), but I can't handle the 'validation' of the checkout_pages (any user can have a checkout_pages of any product, but only this user can see his own checkout_pages).

Comment: @lucastfernandes i made a recommendation below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ProductController**

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return view('products.index', compact('products'));
    }
```

from your view **blade.php** file

```php
@foreach($products as $product)

    @foreach($product->checkout_pages()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get() as $checkoutPage)
        {{ $checkoutPage }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

so `$checkoutPage` hold each **checkout_pages** for the `$product` coming from each **products**

Comment: tks for your answer, but it's still not validating the user_id of the chekout_pages. It's getting the checkout_pages of all users

Comment: use `$product->checkout_pages()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()` in the inner foreach loop

Comment: The pleasure is mine, glad I was able to help out